# flutter-datatable : scrolling widgets out of screen in horizontal scroll-view

Tags: flutter, datatable

I am  making custom dataTable with using row, column and SingleChildScrollView.
here my requirement is header must be sticky and table rows must have bidirectional scrollable.
I get vertical scrolling but while I scroll horizontally widgets move outside of screen infinitely.
have any solution or suggest best plugin/Package for flutter web. (i am making admin panel with flutter web).

i need table like this.

[image]

```
 I tried to datatable,datatable2,PaginatedDataTable but problem is this table's row elements take same width and, i need row elements width as per content have it, and row element must have take a widget so that i can add Text,button or as per need in table.
```

CODE

```
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyCustomDataTable extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyCustomDataTable({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Container(
        height: size.height,
        width: size.width,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(
            color: Colors.grey,
            width: 0.45,
          ),
        ),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          dragStartBehavior: DragStartBehavior.down,
          clipBehavior: Clip.none,
          keyboardDismissBehavior: ScrollViewKeyboardDismissBehavior.onDrag,
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Row(
                children: List.generate(
                  30,
                  (index) => Container(
                    width: 80,
                    height: 30,
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
                    color: Colors.purple,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text("${1 + index}"),
                    ),
                  ),
                ).toList(),
              ),
              Row(
                children: List.generate(
                  30,
                  (index) => Container(
                    width: 80,
                    height: 30,
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
                    color: Colors.purple,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text("${1 + index}"),
                    ),
                  ),
                ).toList(),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 20),
              Flexible(
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: double.maxFinite,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: 50,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Row(
                        children: List.generate(
                          30,
                          (index) => Container(
                            width: 80,
                            height: 30,
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
                            color: Colors.purple.withOpacity(index / 30),
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text("${1 + index}"),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ).toList(),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I am getting same result with help of lazy_data_table: ^0.3.1 , but for than i did lots of changes in lazyDataTable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am getting same output as i want.
for that i was used **[*lazy_data_table*](https://pub.dev/packages/lazy_data_table)**

actually I made lots of changes as per requred and then i achieve this result.And lots of changes i am doing continuously.

Here i made LazyDataTable2 Class/Component base on [**LazyDataTable**](https://pub.dev/packages/lazy_data_table).

And This LazyDataTable2 is giving me result as i want.

**Code**

```
class LazyDataTable2 extends StatefulWidget {
  final int rows, columns;
  final Widget Function(int, int) dataCellBuilder;
  final double topHeaderHeight, leftHeaderWidth, cellHeight, cellWidth;
  final double flexFactor;
  final Map<int, double> customCellWidth;
  final List<DataTableHeader> header;
  final Widget Function(int)? leftHeaderBuilder;
  final Widget? topLeftCornerWidget;
  LazyDataTable2({
    super.key,
    required this.rows,
    required this.columns,
    required this.dataCellBuilder,
    this.topHeaderHeight = 38,
    this.cellHeight = 33,
    this.cellWidth = 80,
    this.leftHeaderWidth = 00, // 100 is best value
    this.flexFactor = 0, //  0.625,
    this.customCellWidth = const <int, double>{},
    required this.header,
    this.leftHeaderBuilder,
    this.topLeftCornerWidget,
  })  : assert(
          (flexFactor == 0 && leftHeaderWidth == 0) ||
              flexFactor != 0 && leftHeaderWidth != 0,
          "flexFactor & leftHeaderWidth both have zero value on not zero value: ErrorMsg",
        ),
        assert(
          columns != 0,
          "number of columns can't be zero so, columns!=0 this is not true here : ErrorMsg ",
        ),
        assert(
          header.isNotEmpty && header.length == columns,
          "header must not empty and header have same length as number of column : ErrorMsg",
        ),
        assert(
          header.every(
            (element) {
              final bool res =
                  (element.header != null && element.headerText == null) ||
                      (element.header == null && element.headerText != null);
              return res;
            },
          ),
          "for each and every element of header you can used either header as widget or headerText as String,only one of them : ErrorMsg",
        );

  @override
  State<LazyDataTable2> createState() => _LazyDataTable2State();
}

class _LazyDataTable2State extends State<LazyDataTable2> {
  final List<double> _flex = <double>[];
  final List<double> _minRowWidth = <double>[];
  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(
      (_) {
    List.generate(
          widget.header.length,
          (index) {
            _flex.add(widget.header[index].flex); // add a flex
            _minRowWidth.add(
              widget.header[index].minWidth,
            ); // add a min rowWidth
          },
        );
        if (mounted) setState(() {});
        printingWork();
      },
    );

    super.initState();
  }

  void printingWork() {
    debugPrint('flex => $_flex');

    _minRowWidth.forEach((element) {
      final i = _minRowWidth.indexOf(element);
      debugPrint('__minRowWidth[$i] => $element');
    });
  }

  final BoxBorder _boxBorder = Border.all(
    color: Colors.transparent,
    width: 0.225,
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
            border: Border.all(
              color: grey400,
              width: 0.45,
            ),
          ),
          child: LayoutBuilder(
            builder: (context, constraints) {
              final maxWidth = constraints.maxWidth;
              final equal = maxWidth / (widget.columns);

              /// sum of total flex => sigmaFlex
              final sigmaFlex =
                  _flex.reduce((previous, next) => previous + next);

              final List<int> keys =
                  List.generate(_flex.length, (index) => index);

              final List<double> values = List.generate(
                _flex.length,
                (index) => max(
                  (equal * widget.columns) * (_flex[index] / sigmaFlex),
                  _minRowWidth[index],
                ),
              );

              final customCellWidth =
                  Map<int, double>.fromIterables(keys, values);

              debugPrint('sigmaFlex => $sigmaFlex');
              debugPrint('equal => $equal');
              debugPrint('values => $values');
              debugPrint('customCellWidth => $customCellWidth');
              debugPrint('maxWidth => $maxWidth :  Size =>  $size');

              //  assigned width
              _flex.forEach((element) {
                final w = (equal * widget.columns) * (element / sigmaFlex);
                final int index = _flex.indexOf(element);
                debugPrint(
                    'rowWidth => calculated : $w  =>  Used[$index] : ${max(w, _minRowWidth[index])}');
              });
              debugPrint(
                'calculatedWidth : ${values.reduce((value, element) => value + element)}',
              );

              return ConstrainedBox(
                constraints: BoxConstraints(
                  maxHeight: (widget.cellHeight) * (widget.rows) +
                      widget.topHeaderHeight +
                      1.2,
                  maxWidth: maxWidth,
                  minHeight: 0.0,
                  minWidth: 0.0,
                ),
                child: LazyDataTable(
                  tableTheme: LazyDataTableTheme(
                    columnHeaderColor: primaryPallet5,
                    columnHeaderBorder: const Border(
                      left: BorderSide(
                        color: grey400,
                        width: 0.45,
                      ),
                      bottom: BorderSide(
                        color: grey400,
                        width: 0.45,
                      ),
                    ),
                    cellBorder: const Border(
                      left: BorderSide(
                        color: grey400,
                        width: 0.45,
                      ),
                    ),
                    rowHeaderBorder: _boxBorder,
                    cornerColor: primaryPallet5,
                    cornerBorder: const Border(
                      bottom: BorderSide(
                        color: grey400,
                        width: 0.45,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  rows: widget.rows,
                  columns: widget.columns,
                  tableDimensions: LazyDataTableDimensions(
                    cellHeight: widget.cellHeight,
                    cellWidth: widget.cellWidth,
                    customCellHeight: {},
                    customCellWidth: widget.customCellWidth.isNotEmpty
                        ? widget.customCellWidth
                        : customCellWidth,
                    topHeaderHeight: widget.topHeaderHeight,
                    leftHeaderWidth: widget.leftHeaderWidth,
                    bottomHeaderHeight: 0.0,
                    rightHeaderWidth: 0.0,
                  ),
                  dataCellBuilder: widget.dataCellBuilder,
                  topLeftCornerWidget: widget.topLeftCornerWidget,
                  topHeaderBuilder: (i) {
                    if (widget.header[i].header != null) {
                      return SizedBox(
                        child: widget.header[i].header,
                      );
                    } else {
                      return Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          left: 15,
                          top: 8,
                          right: 15,
                        ),
                        child: Text(
                          "${widget.header[i].headerText}",
                          style: MyTextStyles.medium.copyWith(
                            color: appPrimary,
                            fontSize: 14.5,
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                  },
                  leftHeaderBuilder: widget.leftHeaderBuilder,
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),

        /// *page controller
        /// !Future Reference
      ],
    );
  }
}

class DataTableHeader {
  final String? headerText;
  final Widget? header;
  final double minWidth, flex;

  DataTableHeader({
    this.headerText,
    this.header,
    this.minWidth = 100, // set default value
    this.flex = 1, // set default value
  });
}
```

**Sample Example**

```
class CustomerNotAgree extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomerNotAgree({super.key});

  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> rows = const [
    {
      'title': 'Battery',
      'date': '29/04/2023',
    },
    {
      'title': 'Tire',
      'date': '29/04/2023',
    },
    {
      'title': 'Head Lights',
      'date': '29/04/2023',
    },
    {
      'title': 'Water Albo Upper',
      'date': '29/04/2023',
    },
    {
      'title': 'Air Filter ',
      'date': '29/04/2023',
    },
    {
      'title': 'Oil Filter',
      'date': '29/04/2023',
    },
    {
      'title': 'Engine Oil',
      'date': '29/04/2023',
    },
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScreenLayout(
      isSecondaryAppBar: true,
      child: Padding(
        padding: Responsive.isDesktop(context)
            ? desktopPadding
            : Responsive.isTablet(context)
                ? tabletPadding
                : mobilePadding,
        child: LazyDataTable2(
          rows: rows.length,
          columns: 3,
          header: [
            DataTableHeader(
              flex: 0.5,
              minWidth: 60,
              headerText: 'No.',
            ),
            DataTableHeader(
              flex: 4.5,
              minWidth: 180,
              headerText: 'Parts / Service Name',
            ),
            DataTableHeader(
              flex: 4,
              minWidth: 100,
              headerText: 'Date',
            ),
          ],
          dataCellBuilder: (r, c) {
            final srNo = r;
            if (c == 0) {
              return Padding(
                padding: tableCellPadding,
                child: Text(
                  '${srNo + 1}',
                  style: tableFirstColumnStyle,
                ),
              );
            } else if (c == 1) {
              return Padding(
                padding: tableCellPadding,
                child: Text(
                  rows[srNo]['title'],
                  style: tableColumnStyle,
                ),
              );
            } else {
              return Padding(
                padding: tableCellPadding,
                child: Text(
                  rows[srNo]['date'],
                  style: tableColumnStyle,
                ),
              );
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Result of my latest Example (From my flutter-web work)
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Did you try [syncfusion_flutter_datagrid](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_datagrid)? It helps you to create and customise complex data tables with different functions and binding.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. yeah I try this, this is not work as i need.